# Stop PHP From Executing From a Variable

Tags: php, security

So I have some PHP code that selects a random line from a text file and displays it. In the future, I want users to be able to add their own lines to that text file to be

```
<?php
$f_contents = file("/path/to/randumb.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$jeff= $line;

echo $jeff;
?>
```

This works fine, however while I was testing it I threw "`<?php echo this site has no security!;?>`" into the randumb.txt file and the result came out blank (which means the PHP code is executing)

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Change your line in to `<?php echo "this site has no security!";?>`

Comment: I probably should have been more clear, I want the code to NOT execute at all. I just want the text on the line to display

Comment: _"the result came out blank"_ <- did you happen to view the result in an HTML document? It's probably not blank at all (hint: view the page source). I'd say there's no chance the line of text is executing as PHP

Comment: If you are displaying this in HTML, I suggest you use `echo htmlspecialchars($jeff);`

Comment: if you run this script with `php script.php` you'll never execute any code in `randumb.txt`. If you plan to use the output from this script however (like run it through php again for example) Then you need to sanitize it first!

Comment: Oh interesting, it came out like this: <!--?php echo security free since the beginning of the internet!; ?--> 

Is there any way to have it so that the physical string displayed to users looks exactly like `<?php echo security free since the beginning of the internet!;?>`

Comment: Or even http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php if you want to output PHP.

Comment: I said view the page source (Ctrl+u), not the DOM inspector in your dev tools. Also, you may have missed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635816/stop-php-from-executing-from-a-variable#comment88281568_50635816)

Comment: (or cmd + alt + u on mac) The DOM inspector is JS driven and tries to correct so it can process.